# VBA Excel ADO sp_addextendedproperty stored procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a userform in Excel which allows users to add new column and description to it to an existing SQL server table.

I do with ADO library in VBA. To add description to a column created I need to run a system stored procedure sp_addextendedproperty.

I can't pass parameters to it, I always receive an error
**Error -2147217900: An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty'.**

```
Private Sub InsertField_bt_Click()
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Provider = "sqloledb"
    sConnectionString = "Server=rumossql12;Database=PharmNet;UID=(login here);Pwd=(password here)"
    con.Open sConnectionString

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_addextendedproperty"

    Dim name As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim value As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim level0type As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim level0name As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim level1type As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim level1name As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim level2type As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim level2name As ADODB.Parameter

    Set name = cmd.CreateParameter("@name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'MS_Description'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append name

    Set value = cmd.CreateParameter("@value", adVariant, adParamInput, , "N'" & InsertField.TextBox2.value & "'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append value

    Set level0type = cmd.CreateParameter("@level0type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'SCHEMA'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append level0type

    Set level0name = cmd.CreateParameter("@level0name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'dbo'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append level0name

    Set level1type = cmd.CreateParameter("@level1type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'TABLE'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append level1type

    Set level1name = cmd.CreateParameter("@level1name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'tbConsolidator'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append level1name

    Set level2type = cmd.CreateParameter("@level2type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'COLUMN'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append level2type

    Set level2name = cmd.CreateParameter("@level2name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'" & InsertField.TextBox1.value & "'")
    cmd.Parameters.Append level2name

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler


    sSQL = "ALTER TABLE PharmNet.dbo.tbConsolidator ADD " & InsertField.TextBox1.value & " NVARCHAR(255) NULL"
    'con.Execute sSQL
    cmd.Execute
    InsertField.Hide

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "ErrorThingy"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).value = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Why can it happen?
Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Quick one - it seems that there is mess with adVarWChar/adVarChar. I have no idea why you want to use Unicode for all parameters, but if you do - keep it consistent.

Comment: @Juliusz The specs for addextendedproperty ask for a levelxtype of type 'sysname', which is basically a nvarchar(128) and levelxname, which is varchar. Hence the mixed parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the example code for `sp_addextendedproperty()` on MSDN, I see the `levelxtype` parameters entered with the first letter capitalised only:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'Caption', 
@value = 'Postal code is a required column.',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = 'Address',
@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = 'PostalCode';
GO
```

Example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047.aspx)

Perhaps you could try that?

EDIT

When I place your code next to the example, it seems to me you're reversing Name and Type. Try this:

```
Set name = cmd.CreateParameter("@name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'MS_Description'")
cmd.Parameters.Append name

Set value = cmd.CreateParameter("@value", adVariant, adParamInput, , "N'" & InsertField.TextBox2.value & "'")
cmd.Parameters.Append value

Set level0type = cmd.CreateParameter("@level0type", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'Schema'")
cmd.Parameters.Append level0type

Set level0name = cmd.CreateParameter("@level0name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 128, "'dbo'")
cmd.Parameters.Append level0name

Set level1type = cmd.CreateParameter("@level1type", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'Table'")
cmd.Parameters.Append level1type

Set level1name = cmd.CreateParameter("@level1name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 128, "'tbConsolidator'")
cmd.Parameters.Append level1name

Set level2type = cmd.CreateParameter("@level2type", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 128, "N'Column'")
cmd.Parameters.Append level2type

Set level2name = cmd.CreateParameter("@level2name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 128, "'" & InsertField.TextBox1.value & "'")
cmd.Parameters.Append level2name
```

Comment: My Schema is called dbo, table - tbConsolidator, and column name must be entered by user. I tried to change them to Dbo, TbConsolidator and enter new column name with first capital letter, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was about types, not names. N'Schema', 
N'Table',  N'Column don't work also.

Comment: @AlexeyNikolaev Shame, I can't find anything else/obvious in your code. One other suggestion I found was to change `cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` to `cmd.CommandType = 4` (4 is the enumerated value of adCmdStoredProc), but that was concernnig a completely different error message...

Comment: @AlexeyNikolaev One other thing: scrap the "N'" in the adVarChar parameters. The N in front of a string makes it Unicode, and you're now inputting Unicode in non-Unicode fields. That may be your conflict.

Comment: Thank you anyway) With cmd.CommandType = 4 nothing changed, I still receive the same error.

Comment: @AlexeyNikolaev I've edited my answer; seems to me you're reversing Name and Type parameter-type-wise.